# Empty UIPickerView when selecting elements

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I want to use a uipickerview to select an element from an array of objects. The picker is hidden and it's shown only when i tap on an textfield. The problem is that the picker is empty.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
import UIKit

class LoginController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var currStruttura : Struttura?

    var  lista_strutture : [Struttura] = [Struttura(id: 1, nome: "uno", banner: "", codice: "", tennis: true, registrazione: true, iscrizione: true),Struttura(id: 2, nome: "due", banner: "", codice: "", tennis: true, registrazione: true, iscrizione: true),Struttura(id: 3, nome: "tre", banner: "", codice: "", tennis: true, registrazione: true, iscrizione: true)]

    @IBOutlet var struttura: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var strutture: UIPickerView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.struttura.inputView = strutture
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.lista_strutture.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return self.lista_strutture[row].getNome()
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.currStruttura = self.lista_strutture[row]
        self.struttura.text = self.lista_strutture[row].getNome()
    }
}
```

And `Struttura.getNome()` returns a string

Comment: try  `self.strutture.reloadAllComponents()`. Try reloading your `UIPickerView` in `ViewDidLoad`

Comment: is ur delegate and datasource assigned to pickerView

Comment: @DheerajSingh yes, it is

Comment: have u tried assigning a simple array and seeing whether ur pickerView is filling or not